# Why does SQL Server use exclusive locks on the entire table to update one record?

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

We have problems with deadlocks, judging by the logs, two requests simultaneously want to get exclusive access to the table. However, both queries change one record in the table.

The error occurs at high loads. There was a lack of RAM. In this case, we use the READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT isolation level. I understand that this isolation level is very dependent on temporary tables and if there is a lack of memory, then it will not lead to anything good. But I'm trying to explain why an exclusive table lock occurs, what is the reason?

Error log:

```
<deadlock>
  <victim-list>
    <victimProcess id="process15869047848" />
    <victimProcess id="process1508af0f088" />
  </victim-list>
  <process-list>
    <process id="process15869047848" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="OBJECT: 8:398376934:0 " waittime="344" ownerId="1381853939" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2020-12-29T14:08:38.100" XDES="0x15803072430" lockMode="X" schedulerid="6" kpid="2276" status="suspended" spid="130" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2020-12-29T14:08:38.093" lastbatchcompleted="2020-12-29T14:08:38.093" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.093" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="KITZBUEHEL" hostpid="12192" loginname="eseddadmin" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1381853939" currentdb="8" currentdbname="SEDD3_KIO" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673187936" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="SEDD3_KIO.dbo.spSaveRouteControlInfo" line="39" stmtstart="1978" stmtend="3056" sqlhandle="0x03000800f5d97d180d9d560172ac000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
update WF4_Routes set
      IsControlled = @IsControlled
     ,UrgencyType = @UrgencyType 
     ,ImportanceType = @ImportanceType 
     ,ControlDate = @ControlDate
     ,ControlAssignmentType = @ControlAssignmentType
     ,ControlState = ISNULL(@ControlState, ControlState)
     ,CompleteDate = case when CompleteDate is null then null else isnull(@ClosingState, CompleteDate) end
     ,State = ISNULL(@State, State)
     ,ModifyDate = GETDATE() 
     ,UserUID = @OperatorUID
    where DocUID = @DocUID and Type = 1 and PRUZ &lt;&gt;    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 8 Object Id = 410900981]   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process1508af0f088" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="OBJECT: 8:398376934:0 " waittime="344" ownerId="1381845648" transactionname="UPDATE" lasttranstarted="2020-12-29T14:08:34.970" XDES="0x1529c41a430" lockMode="X" schedulerid="11" kpid="6748" status="suspended" spid="112" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2020-12-29T14:08:34.957" lastbatchcompleted="2020-12-29T14:08:34.947" lastattention="2020-12-29T14:03:46.567" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="KITZBUEHEL" hostpid="12192" loginname="eseddadmin" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1381845648" currentdb="8" currentdbname="SEDD3_KIO" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673187936" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="SEDD3_KIO.dbo.spSetDocumentViewed" line="38" stmtstart="2690" stmtend="2940" sqlhandle="0x0300080066d77227034cbf0091ac000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
update WF4_Routes set RouteVersion = isnull(RouteVersion, 1) + 1 where DocUID = @DocUID and Type = 2 and State in (1, 2, 7, 8    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 8 Object Id = 661837670]   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process1586903f468" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="OBJECT: 8:398376934:0 " waittime="345" ownerId="1381845814" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2020-12-29T14:08:35.470" XDES="0x155c3ab16f0" lockMode="X" schedulerid="5" kpid="10540" status="suspended" spid="97" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2020-12-29T14:08:35.877" lastbatchcompleted="2020-12-29T14:08:35.457" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.457" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="KITZBUEHEL" hostpid="12192" loginname="eseddadmin" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1381845814" currentdb="8" currentdbname="SEDD3_KIO" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673187936" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="SEDD3_KIO.dbo.spSetRouteCompleted" line="183" stmtstart="12918" stmtend="13284" sqlhandle="0x03000800ae876e11b1312c018cac000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
insert into @RoutesToClose (RouteId, DocUID)
                        select R.ID, @docUID
                        from WF4_Routes R with (UPDLOCK)
                        where R.DocUID = @docUID and R.State in (1, 2, 8) and R.Type =    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 8 Object Id = 292456366]   </inputbuf>
    </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
    <objectlock lockPartition="0" objid="398376934" subresource="FULL" dbid="8" objectname="SEDD3_KIO.dbo.WF4_Routes" id="lock154ab1c5d00" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="398376934">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process1586903f468" mode="IX" />
        <owner id="process1508af0f088" mode="IX" />
        <owner id="process1586903f468" mode="X" requestType="convert" />
        <owner id="process1508af0f088" mode="X" requestType="convert" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process15869047848" mode="X" requestType="convert" />
      </waiter-list>
    </objectlock>
    <objectlock lockPartition="0" objid="398376934" subresource="FULL" dbid="8" objectname="SEDD3_KIO.dbo.WF4_Routes" id="lock154ab1c5d00" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="398376934">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process15869047848" mode="IX" />
        <owner id="process15869047848" mode="X" requestType="convert" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process1508af0f088" mode="X" requestType="convert" />
      </waiter-list>
    </objectlock>
    <objectlock lockPartition="0" objid="398376934" subresource="FULL" dbid="8" objectname="SEDD3_KIO.dbo.WF4_Routes" id="lock154ab1c5d00" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="398376934">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process15869047848" mode="IX" />
        <owner id="process1508af0f088" mode="IX" />
        <owner id="process15869047848" mode="X" requestType="convert" />
        <owner id="process1508af0f088" mode="X" requestType="convert" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process1586903f468" mode="X" requestType="convert" />
      </waiter-list>
    </objectlock>
  </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

**UPDATE 15:07**
I think I found the reason, you asked if the UPDLOCK hint is needed, I decided to check how it affects the locking and found that this kind of hint locks the entire table. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?
An example of using UPDLOCK in our condition:

```
select R.ID, R.DocUID from WF4_Routes R with (UPDLOCK) where R.DocUID = @docUID
```

DocUID index is available.

**UPDATE 15:47**
Now we have found that if UPDLOCK is used with a search condition on a non-clustered index, then it locks the entire table. If it is clustered, then everything is fine, only those records that are specified in the where clause are blocked. It's strange that the manual for using this hint doesn't say anything about it.

Comment: You'll have to look into the query plan. Does it do table scans due to lack of indexes?

Comment: @Cedersved, is it important at the READ COMMITED SNAPSHOT isolation level? I read that indexes are important only if the level is Serializable.

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts, Shouldn't lock escalation check if it can occupy the entire table? I read that ms sql tries to lock the entire table and if it works, then only in this case the entire table is locked at once.

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts, Yes, we use UPDLOCK to lock the records in the table, which will later be changed in the stored procedure

Comment: @MiXaiL, the lock escalation can occur before the other transaction even exists. Since you insert them in a table variable, it's probably more then 1 row. If these rows are scattered over multiple pages, chances are you will get a table lock. Since you requested an UPDLOCK on the rows. The escalation would also happen, without the hint, but only at the moment the update occurs .  The best thing you can do, to avoid the deadlock, is make your stored procedure faster.

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts, Thanks for pointing out the right direction to find the cause of the block. I have changed the description of the problem in the question. The table is locked even if I try to UPDLOCK one record. Could it be that the problem is in our chosen READ COMMITED SNAPSHOT isolation level?

Comment: process15869037088 is running at serializable isolation level. Is that intentional? What do the execution plans look like? Are ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS and ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS both on?

Comment: @MartinSmith, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS and ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS are both ON. We use the READ COMMITED SNAPSHOT isolation level in the error log, this can be seen.

Comment: @MiXaiL, indexes are important to improve concurrency regardless of the isolation level or whether the `READ_COMMITED_SNAPSHOT` database option is on. Upload the execution plans to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the links to your question.

Comment: Have a look at the deadlock graph. It shows serializable isolation level is coming from somewhere - ah hold on I looked at the first version of this Q pre migration. Looks like it changed quite dramatically https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65490375/revisions

Answer (score 1):

The reason for blocking the entire table was that ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = OFF and ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF were disabled on our index. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: http://lurkmore.to/%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%97%D0%91